# How to customize the offset options for grid in Bootstrap using Less

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I want to reduce the the width by which `col-md-offset-1` of **bootstrap** assigns `margin-left` at a certain place. I would prefer this to be done by using  LESS.

Comment: I do not understand why this question should be closed for being too broad. I fact there is only one answer use a media query (`@media (min-width: 992px)`) to set your custom margin. Two possible answer have nothing to do with the question itself. Also a short question can be a good question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't really need Less for this since the solution there would be exactly the same as in pure CSS. Just override the corresponding property:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .col-md-offset-1 {
       margin-left: 42%; /* <- your value here */
    }
}
```

In Less you could modify the method Bootstrap generates all such `offset` classes (by overriding/cascading [these mixin and variables](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.4/less/mixins/grid-framework.less#L71)) but that would be an overkill for that tiny change you actually need).

Comment: perfect!!! just what i wanted ...

Comment: can u suggest a good tutorial for jumping into LESS ?

Comment: http://www.cssauthor.com/less-tutorials/

Comment: Excellent solution. Thanks. I agree question should not have been closed.

Answer (score 0):

@seven-phases-max wrote:

> You don't really need Less for this since the solution there would be
>   exactly the same as in pure CSS.

I don't agree with that. Bootstrap uses Less to help you code DRY (don't repeat yourself). When your start hard coding your changes, your changes will break in future when you change some of the framework parameters.

Changing the behaviour of the `.col-md-offset-1` depends on the `@screen-md-min` variable which sets the `min-width` for the media query, see: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries

```
/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }
```

So in my opinion your Less code should look like that shown beneath:

```
@import "bootstrap"
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {  
  .col-md-offset-1 {
   margin-left: 42%; /* <- your value here */
  }
}
```

Using the above you should notice that you can not recompile Bootstrap without running the autoprefixer, see: http://bassjobsen.weblogs.fm/compile-bootstrap-less-v2-autoprefix-plugin/

To keep you changes future proof you should also consider to make your modification only be applied for the situation where you need it (and do not change the properties of the predefined `.col-md-offset-1` itself). For instance by using a unique parent of your grid;

**html**

```
<div id="maincontent"><div class="container"><class="row"><div class=".col-md-offset-1">
```

**less**

```
@import "bootstrap"
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {  
  #maincontent .col-md-offset-1 {
   margin-left: 42%; /* <- your value here */
  }
}
```

Comment: Fair point. My assumption was just that if this is the only (or may one of a few same tiny changes) modification the OP wants to apply to his theme setting-up a complete Bootstrap built tool chain and compiling it from scratch may be really an overkill for one who's not yet familiar with all this.